# how to add clweeklycalendarview delegate in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I got error : does not conform to protocol CLWeeklyCalendarViewDelegate,
Please give any solution for problem, I don't know what are the missing methods in my class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to confirm protocol to the delegate by adding `CLWeeklyCalendarViewDelegate>` ahead to interface

In Objective C

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <CLWeeklyCalendarViewDelegate>
```

In Swift

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, CLWeeklyCalendarViewDelegate{

}
```

Comment: I am using swift language Please give solution to add CLWeeklyCalendarviewdelegate in  swift

Answer (score 0):

First you need to confirm the protocol by writing

```
    calendarWeekView.delegate = self
```

Also define your protocol at top while defining the class as below

```
    class YourSwiftClass: UIViewController, CLWeeklyCalendarViewDelegate
```

Implement the delegate method as below

```
func dailyCalendarViewDidSelect(_ date: Date!) {

}
```